# Cannot cast an object to its parent object in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

In C# we can do something like this:

`Honda a = new Car();` and that works but the same one doesn't work in Visual Basic.NET (I am fairly new to Visual Basic)

`Dim a as Honda = new Car` and it says Unable to cast object of type 'SampleApp.Car' to type 'SampleApp.Honda'.

What's wrong here?

Here is my sample code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As B = New A
        Console.WriteLine(a.DoSOmething())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Class A
    Public Overridable Function DoSOmething() As String
        Return "SOmething"
    End Function
End Class

Class B
    Inherits A

    Public Overrides Function DoSOmething() As String
        Return "Something else"
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: If you have `class Honda : Car { }` you should also get a type conversion error in C# with `Honda a = new Car();` Your question would be clearer if you named the classes consistently, and in your code you used `Honda` and `Car`. Otherwise you could have used `B` and `A` in the explanation. It is not clear from your question if `Honda Inherits Car` although you would expect it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Honda is more specific than a car, and may include additional features or behavior.  You can cast a Honda to a Car without issue, but not a Car to a Honda.

edit: Example, a Honda may include an ActivateVTEC method, while all Cars will have a Refuel method, so if you were able to create a Honda = new Car, ActivateVTEC would be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You've got this wrong. You can never cast A as B.

This would be the valid statement:

```
 Dim instance as A = New B
```

An `A` can contain an instance of B, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit mixed since you mention the classes `Honda` and `Car` but in the code you have classes `A` and `B`.
I am presuming in your C# code you have

```
class Honda : Car {  }
```

In that case

```
Honda a = new Car(); // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Car' to 'Honda'
```

is trying to assign an object of type `Car` to a reference of type `Honda`. Assuming you have `class Honda : Car { }`, you are thus trying to assign an object of the parent type `Car` to a reference of the child type `Honda`. Your question says, "Cannot cast an object to its **parent** object", but you are in fact trying to do the opposite based on the code you've provided and the assumption.
Thus even in C# you should also get the compiler error of `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Car' to 'Honda'`. It should not work as you say.

This is due to the way inheritance works, which applies to VB and C# alike (and other OO languages such as Java).

`Honda` and `B` in your example are lower in the class hierarchy to `Car` and `A`. Meaning they have at least all the properties of their Base classes (aka Superclass or Parent class). As such the compiler can't implicitly convert a Base class to a more specialised class, although it can implicitly convert a more specialised class to its base class.
That is why assigning an object of type `Car` to a variable of type `Honda` will cause a compiler error in the absence of an explicit type conversion. However you could assign an object of type `Honda` to a variable of type `Car`, or an object of type `B` to a variable of type `A` like this

```
Dim myHonda as Car = New Honda()
Dim bObject as A = New B()
```

or in C#

```
Car myHonda = new Honda();
A bObject = new B();
```